# How can I share a resource file between projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources

I am using C# and how can I code to share a resource file between my projects in the same solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a resx to an empty class project, change the visibility type on the editor from internal to public and then reference that project from both other projects.

http://blog.dmbcllc.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/image.png
(from: http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2009/04/02/silverlight-resx-files-and-internationalization/)

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't see the visibility type :)

Comment: I believe that answer only applies to WP not Forms.